# Can DevicePolicyManager.lockNow() be called from a non-admin app?

Tags: android, device-admin

These document the use of `lockNow()` from an app that's admin.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow(int)

http://blogs.quovantis.com/android-device-administration-apis/

The basic process is:

1. create a `DeviceAdminReceiver`
2. register the receiver in the manifest, and give it the `DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED` action
3. declare the security policies in an xml file
4. initialize a `DevicePolicyManager` object in your `onCreate()` method
5. call `DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()`

And that works beautifully. However, I'd like to be able to lock the screen without making my app an administrator perhaps by calling `lockNow()` as an implicit intent. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a device admin with the right permissions can call that API.

Given that, either you must:

1. Create an app that is a device admin with the USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK permission and triggers on an intent of your choosing.
2. Make your existing app a device admin with the USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK permission.
3. Find an existing app with those requirements. But I am not familiar with any.